# SimpleDateFormat parser

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I need to transform a date from this format : Tue Dec 10 09:00:00 EET 2013 into 3 12 2013 09:00

I've tried something like:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
Date newdata = dateFormat.parse(pubDate);
SimpleDateFormat desiredDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm");
this.pubDate = desiredDateFormat.parse(desiredDateFormat.format(newdata));
```

but the date is not changing. How I can accomplish this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can use the JodaTime library, it´s way better than java Date.

Comment: `Tue Dec 10 09:00:00 EET 2013` into `3 10 2013 09:00`? where does the `3` come from? What is the value of `pubDate` can you post it..

Comment: 3 is the day of the month

Comment: What is `10` then? You do not want the month.. because i don't see `dec` or `12`?

Comment: Yes..you're right -I've edited my question...so the format I need is 3-12-2013 09:00

Comment: Your date format for input should be "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" or "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy" or "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy". But in my tests, neither of these parsed "EET" successfully. There must be something with timezones.

Answer (score 1):

This simple line will solve your problem

```
android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat= new android.text.format.DateFormat();
dateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", new java.util.Date());
```

Comment: 1st try to get the Output Log from SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"); so you can make sure Interpretation of Time is working